# Java Swing GUI closing randomly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My problem is quite weird: even if I create a JFrame with literally nothing in it, so it should just display a white window, but it crashes after doing anything with it. For example, when I resize the window, the new, resized area will be black in most cases (or sometimes be the right color I really don't know why) and it will either just close or display "Not responding" and then close after a few seconds.
GUI class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private static JFrame frame;

    public GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("test");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    }
}
```

And here's an image exactly showing the behavior: [image]
Why does it behave like this? It's most definitely not because of the code, I think. It must be something else. I tried reinstalling Java, didn't help out. Switched from SDK 13 to 1.8.0_171, nothing. Older programs using Swing also suddenly don't work anymore and behave the same. Any ideas?

Comment: How, exactly, are you running your code?  What IDE is that in the image?

Comment: Also... why extend JFrame and then proceed to declare `private static JFrame frame;` in your class? You should pick one :)

Comment: @sleepToken Thanks for pointing out. Didn't help, but I'll remember in the future if I ever get this stuff to work again

Comment: @azurefrug It's IntelliJ in the image. Also tried Eclipse, getting the same results

Comment: @Blin420 Oh I didn't expect it to fix anything, just to cleanup. I am curious if my answer below fixed your issue, however.

Comment: @sleepToken No, sadly it did not.

Comment: Start by copy-pasting and invoking any tested code like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FrameDemoProject/src/components/FrameDemo.java)  and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Always start your GUI from the event dispatching thread to avoid unwanted behavior.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      GUI gui = new GUI();
    }
  });
}
```

See the javadoc: [invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

Answer (score 0):

Try this (width 400, height 300):

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private static JFrame frame;

    public GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("test");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and it gave me a window in minimal size (even when specifying frame.setSize(400, 300);) and it does exactly the same weird stuff like my original code

Comment: add thisline:

setBounds(0, 0, 401, 301);

Comment: Yes, the window is at least properly sized now, but it automatically closes after a second

Comment: What is the point in extending `JFrame` yet creating another one ? Also why set bounds when using a layout manager ?